# JFrame doesn't take the actual screen size

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have been trying to set the size of my JFrame to the exact same size of my screen (2256x1504). 
It also seems to take that size but when I display something the outcome is always bigger than intended.

```
public class Frame extends JFrame {

    public Frame() {
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        int width = 2256;
        int height = 1504;
        Dimension size = new Dimension(width,height);
        p.setPreferredSize(size);
        p.setMinimumSize(size);
        p.setMaximumSize(size);
        p.setSize(size);
        this.setUndecorated(true);
        this.setContentPane(p);
        this.pack();
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add the code you're using

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). (An MRE/SSCCE is a more specific form of problem code than suggested by @Rick. BTW Rick, `[mre]` in a comment automatically expends to [mre].

Comment: Don't put code in comments where it is largely unreadable! Instead [edit] the question to add it above.

Comment: Can it be that the problem is heap space related?

Answer (score 1):

```
int width = 2256;
int height = 1504;
```

Guessing your screen is 2556x1504. You give the frame this size. When we full screen a program (from default button OS gives in upper right corner of the window), it does not get screen's size. It takes screen's size - the height of the OS task bar. I do not know for other operating systems, but if you want to make an undecorated frame full screen in windows and involve the task bar, you have to use this:

```
public class Frame extends JFrame {

    public Frame() {
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        int width = 2256;
        int height = 1504;
        Dimension size = getScreenDimensionWithoutTaskbar(this);
        p.setPreferredSize(size);
        p.setMinimumSize(size);
        p.setMaximumSize(size);
        p.setSize(size);
        this.setUndecorated(true);
        this.setContentPane(p);
        this.pack();
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static Dimension getScreenDimensionWithoutTaskbar(Frame frame) {
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int width = screenSize.width;
        int height = screenSize.height;
        Insets screenInsets = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets(frame.getGraphicsConfiguration());
        int taskBarSize = screenInsets.bottom;
        return new Dimension(width, height - taskBarSize);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Frame();
    }


}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help George Z., but the problem does not seem to be one that is related to the taskbar. I am simply trying to set the size of my JFrame to one that matches the exact resolution of my screen. When I do that the resulting JFrame does take my entire screen but it does not make use of every pixel.

Answer (score 0):

> I have been trying to set the size of my JFrame to the exact same size of my screen (2256x1504).

Don't use magic numbers. Each computer can be using a screen with a different resolution. Let Swing determine the size. Use:

```
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

So the basic structure of the code would be:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
add( panel );
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setAlwaysOnTop(true);
setUndecorated(true);
//setResizable(false); // not needed since the title bar is removed
setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
//pack(); // not needed since the frame will be the screen size
setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help camickr, but when I use your code the resulting screen size does still not make use of every pixel on the screen.

Comment: @randCoder works fine for me. I use JDK 11 or Window 10. The frame covers the screen except for the taskbar on the bottom.  *does still not make use of every pixel on the screen.* - don't know what that means. Post the updated code you used to test my suggestion and a picture of the result.