# Maximize a JFrame | No Fullscreen

Tags: java, swing, jframe, maximize

I want to maximize my JFrame as if you press the button next to Close. So no full-screen mode, you still have to see the taskbar.

I’ve tried several different ways, none of them worked.

e.g. (this makes fullscreen)

```
f.setExtendedState( f.getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

I don't know if that's because my frame is undecorated.

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60787057/jframe-doesnt-take-the-actual-screen-size/60788771#60788771

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

frame.setExtendedState( frame.getExtendedState()|JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH );

Comment: No, that makes full-screen because it is undecorated

Comment: then set it as frame.setUndecorated(false)